# How to use insert statement in a select and return new PK value to put as a field of select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a code about Insert into a table, for example:

```
Insert Into MyTable(PropertyName,PropertyID)
values('PropertyName1', (if exists(select 1 from PropertyTable where propertyName='PropertyName1') return null
else
insert into PropertyTable(Name) values('PropertyName1')
return scope_Identity()))
```

my problem is at there:

```
insert into PropertyTable(Name) values('PropertyName1')
return scope_Identity()
```

I need if my row isn't exist in my table, at first insert new value in a table and then return ID for use in above insert.
but i don't know how do it?

Comment: Is this in a Stored Procedure or Function? Or is it an ad-hoc Insert statement?

Comment: `set @new_id  = scope_identity()` and use it

Comment: @Shaneis Stored Procedure

Comment: @IvanStarostin I know that, please read my question again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your code is completely ok, but a alternative solution for the use of **scope_identity** is **output** clause.

Try this and tell me if works:

```
Insert Into MyTable (PropertyName,PropertyID) values('PropertyName1',
        (if exists(select 1 from PropertyTable where propertyName='PropertyName1') 
                return null
         else
                insert into PropertyTable(Name) 
                output inserted.nameOfYourIDColumn 
                values('PropertyName1')));
```

Comment: No!, it's not work. there is a problem with if in ()

Comment: Where are you trying to put this code? In a stored procedure? Or a regular insert? Lets try to do a sample in http://sqlfiddle.com/ to make things easier.

Comment: what things I found until today show me a Insert can happened into another Insert. and about your last comment: It's wrote into a Stored Procedure.